# Strange merge result with TFS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs

I created a branch off the the main branch in TFS.

There were some updates (new files) on the main branch, so I wanted to merge those into the branch.

**After the merge, the files that were new in the main branch did NOT get merged.**

Why would this be?

These are new files in the main branch.

Comment: Did you merge on latest, on changeset, time...?

Comment: I merged on latest, is that wrong?

Comment: No. that is fine. did you get any conflicts, did you commit the merge? Do you have any pending changes?

Comment: Did you merge main -> your feature branch, or did you merge from your feature branch -> main?

Comment: @EdwardThomson merged main to feature branch.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds familair. I remember we had a problem where it looked like that. Try Checking in.. This helped us.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that you don't have the right to do what you 're after.
When you merge *existing* files you can see in the "Pending Changes" window that the action is "merge, edit".
When you merge *new* files you 'll see "merge, branch". 
In order to fulfill the latter your users must have also "Manager Branch" permission set. In order to check this out, right-click on the branch in Source Control Explorer, select "properties" and then "permissions".
(another, possibly useful tip: in case your *new* files are binaries (DLL, PNG) the action "lock" is also included - so the "Lock" permission must also be set in this case.)